# Merging the result Two queries in Cosmosdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

```sql
SELECT 
count(c.Transaction_Id) as Legacy FROM c where c.OverallStatus = 'COMPLETED' and c.KeyData2 like 'WLS_%'
and contains (c.Created_Date, '2021-08-11') and c.Transaction_Set_Code = '210'
```

```sql
SELECT 
count(c.Transaction_Id) as NonLegacy FROM c where c.OverallStatus = 'COMPLETED' and c.KeyData2 not like 'WLS_%'
and contains (c.Created_Date, '2021-08-11') and c.Transaction_Set_Code = '210'
```

Required Answer :

```json
[
    {
        "Legacy": 18753,
        "NonLegacy": 121862
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. You've provided two queries, each of which produce one of the elements in your JSON. What is your specific issue? Note that the only way you'd be able to "combine" these queries is if you did some type of correlated query (though I haven't tried that for your particular case - just something for you to consider).

Comment: i want to merge above both different queries in one as i want two counts on two different conditions

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried, as well as sample input data.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select t.cnt , t.keyd from (
  SELECT count(1) as cnt, c.keydata2 as keyd 
  FROM c 
  where c.OverallStatus = 'COMPLETED' 
  and contains (c.Created_Date, '2021-08-11')
  and c.Transaction_Set_Code = '210'
  group by c.KeyData2)
t
 where t.keyd like 'wls_%' or t.keyd not like 'wls_%'
```

Comment: @David Makogon, i have written the required query above please check

Answer (score 0):

Well reach on the following solution

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(c.KeyData2 like 'WLS_%' ? 1 : undefined) AS NonLegacy, 
    COUNT(c.KeyData2 not like 'WLS_%' ? 1 : undefined) AS Legacy
from c where contains (c.Created_Date, '2022-01-12') and c.OverallStatus = 'COMPLETED' and c.Transaction_Set_Code = '210'
```

**Output**

```json
"Legacy": 402,
"NonLegacy": 320
```